# How to extract key, value of a list of dict of string

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, key-value

I've tried to find a solution but with no success...

## First I pull the data from a db mysql

```
vod = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from x", conn)
```

## I have a structured DataFrame like that (called df)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
index     id        remuneration    benefits        describe  


500      354           1500         example below     none

501      355           1200         example below     none

502      356           1300         example below     none

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

## column benefits is like that:

```
[{"value":"Insalubre","selected":false},{"value":"Perigoso","selected":false}]
```

## Objective

I want to create 2 new columns on this df => (Insalubre = false or true) and (Perigoso = false or true)

## Details:

```
type(df['benefits'])
```

output: `pandas.core.series.Series`

## When I try

input:

```
for key, value in df.items():
    print(key, value)
```

output:

```
6325 [{"value":"Insalubre","selected":false},{"value":"Perigoso","selected":false}]
```

input:

```
df['benefits']
```

output:

```
0       [{"value":"Insalubre","selected":false},{"valu...

Name: benefits, Length: 6326, dtype: object
```

What way can I do to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['benefits'].tolist()[0])
```

Comment: It didn't work.

I tried: pd.DataFrame([b['benefits'].tolist()[0]])

Output:

                       0
0 [{"value":"Insalubre","selected":false},{"valu...